# Angularjs $routeProvider Config

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple angularjs App called **testAPP**. In it I have a **constant** called **URLS**, which I may also use in other services of this app. now I need to use the **URLS.DASHBOARD_URL** inside templateUrl of the  **$routeProvider**. Is it possbile? If not, then whats the easiest way to achieve this?

```
    (function () {
    angular.module('testAPP', [])

    .constant("URLS", {
        "DASHBOARD_URL": '/modules/dashboard/dashboardUI.html' 
    })

    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

     $routeProvider
                    .when('/', {
                        title: 'website',
                        templateUrl: URLS.DASHBOARD_URL, //Here i need to use
                        controller: '',
                    })

}]);

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `inject` constant into `config` and use it, as follows:

```
(function () {
   angular.module('testAPP', [])

   .constant("URLS", {
        "WEBSITE": '/modules/dashboard/dashboardUI.html'
    })

    .config(['$routeProvider','URLS', function ($routeProvider,URLS) {

     $routeProvider
       .when('/', {
           title: 'website',
           templateUrl: URLS.WEBSITE,
           controller: '',
        })

  }]);
 })();
```